# Singleton Potential Leak?

Tags: ios, xcode, singleton, memory-leaks, analyzer

In one of my third party libraries in my project, the singleton sharedInstance method seems to be throwing up an analyzer warning on the final return_sharedInstance line:

```
+ (BlockBackground*)sharedInstance
{
    if (_sharedInstance != nil) {
        return _sharedInstance;
    }

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (_sharedInstance == nil) {
            [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
        }
    }

    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

Anyway, what is the proper way to actually fix this warning? Also I have seen that you are not supposed to do self alloc in a method like this, is that true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `autorelease`; you need to remove it, but more importantly (thanks @Yaman/@rmaddy) you aren't assigning the allocated object to `_sharedInstance`.

What will happen is that the next time the run loop ends, or the next time the autorelease pool is destroyed, whichever is sooner, the instance will be released. The `_sharedInstance` pointer will be left *dangling* and the next user of the object will fault with *message sent to deallocated instance* (or some such).

Comment: @iBradApps The other answer is more correct. This one is only half right.

Comment: @rmaddy In what way? He says the object is immediately thrown away, which isn't correct; the lifetime of the object is dictated by the autorelease pool it's within.

Comment: Look at the original code. There is no assignment being made to `_sharedInstance`. Hence the allocated object is "thrown away".

Comment: @rmaddy Ah yes, I missed that.

Comment: You should thank Yaman. He noticed it. I overlooked it myself until seeing his answer.

Comment: Naa no worries guys, i'm glad i've helped ;)

Answer (score 5):

Actually your line `[[[self alloc] init] autorelease];` create on object and immediately throw it away. You need to replace with `_sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];`

Comment: Half right. You need to also get rid of the call to `autorelease`.

Comment: Autorelease does not immediately throw away an object.